# AWS S3 with SAML

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oauth, saml

I am trying to upload files to S3 from an app written in JavaScript. For this reason - mobile app, I am limited to libraries that I could use. Got the thing to work by using `FormData` until it was decided to use SAML and delegate authentication. Now, the temporary credentials are being obtained OK. However, AWS::S3 does not want to recognize them. It throws an error: `The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

My code is below:

```
console.log("AWS temp credentials: " + JSON.stringify(delegated_jwt.Credentials));
var aws_creds = delegated_jwt.Credentials;

var secret = aws_creds.SecretAccessKey;
var policyBase64 = base64.encode(JSON.stringify(POLICY_JSON));
console.log ("policy base64: " + policyBase64 );

var signature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(policyBase64, secret));
console.log("signature: " + signature);

var key = "user_uploads" + "/" + delegated_jwt.Subject + '/' + (new Date).getTime() + ".jpg";

console.log("AWS::S3 key: " + key);

var params = new FormData();
params.append('key', key);
params.append('acl', 'private');
params.append('Content-Type', "image/jpeg");     
params.append('AWSAccessKeyId', aws_creds.AccessKeyId);
params.append('policy', policyBase64);
params.append('signature', signature);
params.append('file', captured.uri);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/', true);
xhr.onload = () => {
...
```

When I used permanent access and secret keys, it worked fine. If this there is something wrong with my AWS settings, how do I debug this? What else should I check?

Comment: Take a look at the "AWS temp credentials" console log output... there should be a security token in there, in addition to the key and secret, and you'll need to incorporate that into the form and signing code, since (iirc) that's what tells S3 you're using temporary credentials -- and it won't recognize the access key, otherwise.  Do you see that in the output?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I see the token. What is the key [name] for the token?

Comment: it seems that the header is 'X-Amz-Security-Token' or ...?

Comment: It's `x-amz-security-token`.  It needs to be in the form *and* in the policy (your code seems to start after the policy has been generated). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html